# How to determine if PFFile is Video or Image?

Tags: image, swift, video, parse-platform, pffile

I'm creating an application in IO's with Parse and 
would like to know how can i determine if the file that i get is a Video or an image any ideas? any suggestion ?

Comment: I welcome to SO. Have you tried anything, any code to show us? What tutorials or SO questions have you looked at so far? if you ask specific questions relating to a problem you are having, usually with code, you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: How is the file created? What object owns the reference to it?

Comment: you can get extension of PFFile by using PFFile *file;  [file.name pathExtension];

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedPostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCell
            cell.alpha = 0
        let FeedPost = object as! Post
        
 cell.postImage.file = FeedPost.PFFile here's what what i written in my code the post is an NSObject

Answer (score 0):

here's what I've got so far

```
      if let value = allPost[indexPath.row]["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

        let PFFileURLFromParse = value.url

        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: PFFileURLFromParse!)

      func thumbnailImagePreview() -> UIImage?

        {

            let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: fileUrl!)

            let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

            imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

            imageGenerator.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeEncodedPixels

            do {

                let time: CMTime = CMTime(seconds: 0.0, preferredTimescale:1)

                let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)

                return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

            } catch {

                return nil

            }

        }

       if (fileUrl!.pathExtension!.lowercaseString == "mov"){

            print("Parse image is a mov: \(fileUrl!.pathExtension!.lowercaseString)”);

fileExtenion = "mov";

cell.ImagePost.image = thumbnailImagePreview()

            cell.ImagePost.loadInBackground()

            print("fileExtenion is \(fileExtenion)")

         }

        else{

            fileExtenion = ".png";

            print("DEFAULTING TO file type, Parse image is a png: \(fileUrl!.pathExtension!.lowercaseString)");

        }

        cell.ImagePost.file = value

        cell.ImagePost.loadInBackground()

    }
```

// but the loading for cell is getting is too long how i put it in  collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}